# Facebook ios sdk doesn't track standard purchase events

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, facebook-ios-sdk, in-app-subscription

I have auto-renewable subscriptions in my app. These subscriptions come with 3-7 days trial (money charged only after this trial period). I didn't place any custom code for event tracking in source files, and facebook tracks all of these events just fine, except purchases. I thought that was because I've never had purchase events untill today, but today somebody subscribed, and "purchase" event still not tracked. Instead "Initiated checkout" event was tracked with value = subscription price. [image]

Question is why it is not tracked? I am planning to create an advertising campaign with purchase events optimization in facebook, but if they are not recognized, then I can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-renewable subscriptions can't be tracked by the Facebook SDK since the customer doesn't get charged in response to in-app events. Payment for your subscriptions occur after a trial conversion or on a renewal, and happen regardless of whether the user has your app open at the time.

In order to accurately track auto-renewable subscriptions in Facebook, you'll need to save the purchase receipt from Apple on your server, and periodically refresh it with the `/verifyReceipt` endpoint. From this response you can determine if your free trial converted or the subscription renewed, then, finally, you can track the conversion through the Facebook API from your server.

Comment: so, if I don't have my own server I can't see revenue in Facebook analytics? @enc_life

Comment: Yup. To track it with any accuracy it needs to be done server-side since renewals will recur regardless of any in-app activity.

Comment: There is some service like RevenueCat to count revenue